# Doctrine 2 DQL - Select by exact ManyToMany array

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have ClassA with a ManyToMany relationship to ClassB, is there a way to Select ClassA entities by ClassB array? Currently I have:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("
    SELECT a FROM Bundle:ClassA a 
    JOIN a.classB b 
    WHERE b IN (:classBEntities)
    ")
    ->setParameter('classBEntities', $classBEntities);
```

Being $classBEntities an array of ClassB entities. The problem with that query is that if I'm looking the ClassA entity that have ClassB entities 1, 2 and 3 it returns any ClassA entity that have one of those 3 ClassB entity as well as the one that have the three of them, but I need to select just the ones that have all the entities that the array contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error using nifr answer I got the solution, here it is if someone ran into the same problem:

```
$queryBuilder = $em->getRepository('Bundle:ClassA')
                    ->createQueryBuilder('a')
                    ->join('a.classB', 'b');
                    ->groupBy('a.id')
                    ->having('COUNT(b) = :cB')
                    ->setParameter('cB', count($classBEntities));

           foreach ($classBEntities as $entity) 
           {
               $id = $entity->getId();
               $queryBuilder
                ->join('a.classB', 'b'.$id)
                ->andWhere('b'.$id.'.id IN (:b_entity'.$id.')')
                ->setParameter('b_entity'.$id, array($id));
           }

$result = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$queryBuilder = $em
   ->getRepository('Bundle:ClassA')
   ->createQueryBuilder('a')
   ->leftJoin('a.classB', 'b')
;

foreach ($classBentities as $entity) {
    $queryBuilder
        ->andWhere('b IN (:b_entity)')
        ->setParameter('b_entity', array($entity))
    ;
}

$queryBuilder
   ->add('where', $queryBuilder->expr()->count('b'), '=' , ':count_b')
   ->setParameter('count_b', count($classBentities))

$result = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

You will need Doctrine >= 2.1 for this to work.

Comment: I ran into another problem, if I'm looking for the ClassA that have ClassBs 1,2,3 with that query it returns any ClassA that have those ClassBs despite that have others as well (i.e. 1,2,3,4 ; 1,2,3,5) etc). What I'm looking for is something similar to "WHERE b = :classBEntities" Any thoughts?

Comment: well you didn't say something about this additional requirement in the question :) so basically you want `WHERE b = :classBEntites' as an exact match ... meaning COUNT(b) must aswell match the number of classBEntites in the collection?

Comment: Thank you! That should make it, but thanks to it I've found another problem. In the foreach clause, b_entity is overwritten with every iteration, so if I'm looking for 1,2,3, it looks for 3,3,3 and returns it (the result I've seen before was every "a" with "b" = 3). I've changed to ->setParameter('b_entity'.$i, array($entity)) and it worked in the way that's looking for 1,2,3, but it isn't returning anything. I've looked on profiler and it says "Impossible WHERE", with query extract: AND b1_.id IN (?) AND b1_.id IN (?) AND b1_.id IN (?) Parameters: [[1], [2], [3]]. Should it look like that?